# Problem in aligning equations

Tags: equations, cases, alignment

I am using the code as shown below to write an equation. I have a problem with the alignment. How can I fix it?? Also on the left-hand side of the equation, there is a space between N and D i want the space to be removed too. The code written is:

```
ND_{max}&=&\left\{
        \begin{array}{lr}
        \frac{n}{2} &:  n \hspace*{2mm}  even \\ 
        \frac{n-1}{2} &: n \hspace*{2mm} odd
        \end{array}
        \right. \\
```

The outcome of the code is shown in the picture.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load `amsmath` package and use

```
\[
  ND_{\max} = 
   \begin{cases}
    \frac{n}{2}   & \text{$n$ even,} \\ 
    \frac{n-1}{2} & \text{$n$ odd.}
   \end{cases}
\]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help. It got executed. Also on the left-hand side of the equation, I want to get rid of the space between the letter N and D. How can I do it??

Comment: That space is the default one produced by LaTeX. I would keep it like that. But if you really want to reduce it, insert a negative space with `\!` for example.

Comment: @PratheekHb, you are welcome. Usually the code should be simple and easy to read. If you need to insert many empty spaces by hand, probably there should be a better method. Welcome to TeX world.

Comment: @Sigur - Or, write `\mathit{ND}`. This informs TeX that "N" and "D" aren't the names of two separate variables...